# find: paths must precede expression: find -name

Tags: shell, ssh, find

```
[root@clearsee-single ~]# sshpass -p bagabu ssh -q root@localhost find /opt/ -iname '*.log*' | xargs cp '/tmp/'
find: paths must precede expression: MSTRInstaller.log
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Please advice

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python? Why is it even on Stack Overflow instead of Super User or Unix or something? Your just asking how to use the `ssh` command.

Comment: I'm trying the execute the following:

def logger(src,dst):
        output_csadmin = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', 'bagabu', 'ssh', '-q', 'root@localhost','find', src, '-iname', '*.log*', '|', 'xargs', 'cp', '/tmp/Snapshot/'+dst], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: get the same error on linux CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` uses `system(3)` semantics and not `execve(2)` semantics.

In other words, you need to add a layer of escaping:

```
sshpass -p bagabu ssh -q root@localhost "find /opt/ -iname '*.log*'"
```